# how to display number with sorted list in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I fetch overall data from database and filter data according to list.ENTUSR='kiran'. how can i display number example(1, 2, 3,.. so on) with list.

```
example:-> 1. kiran- hello
2. kiran - hii
3.kiran - okkk
```

-> I need to somehow add count inside list. But I don't know how to do that.

.ts

```
this._servall.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data=>
    {
    this.display=data;
    });
```

.html

```
 <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of display;let i=index;" >
        <ion-item  text-wrap *ngIf="list.ENTUSR='kiran'">
{{list.i}}
    {{list.ENTUSR}}
    {{list.DESCRPITION}}
    </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```

Please guide me the way to achieve this.

> Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you create a working example

Comment: can you show what do you have inside the display array and do you want to display number based on the number inside the array or just start with default value 1 and then increment if list.ENTUSR='kiran'

Comment: you are doing right but just add {{list.i+ 1}} this will give you the incremented value from your array.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/a/48561949/2349407

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what are you looking for, something like this?

```
displayKiran = [];

constructor() {
  this.displayKiran = this.display.filter(dis => {
     return dis.name == 'kiran';
  });
}

<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayKiran;let i=index;" >
    <ion-item  text-wrap>
        {{list.i}} {{list.ENTUSR}} {{list.DESCRPITION}}
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

In constructor, or when you populate display array, filter data with that condition and then loop thrue filtered data, example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-68drb6

Answer (score 0):

You should type `{{i}}` instead of `{{list.i}}` , since **i** is not a member of **list**