# Need to show counter inside ngif in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am fetching data from API on HTML using `ngFor`, but filtering with `ngIf`, see below `home.html` code.

`{{list.i}}` is showing me the array position number (17,18,19...), but I want to show **1,2,3,4..**, how do I do that?

```
 <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of display;let i=index;" >
        <ion-item  text-wrap *ngIf="list.ENTUSR='kiran'">
{{list.i}}
    {{list.ENTUSR}}
    {{list.DESCRPITION}}
    </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here it is what you need

**Component Side :**

```
getUsers(users , name){
    return users.filter((user) => user.name === name);
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of getUsers(users,'Vivek');let i = index;">
  index -> {{ i + 1 }} <br/> 
  id -> {{ user.id}} <br/>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-index-with-condition)**

Answer (score 0):

You should compare as **`===`**

```
 <ion-item  text-wrap *ngIf="list.ENTUSR==='kiran'">
```

and

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of display;let i=index;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let each of list.i" *ngIf="list.ENTUSR='kiran'">
        <ion-item text-wrap>
            {{i}} {{list.ENTUSR}} {{list.DESCRPITION}}
        </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: but how will this change the value of i ?

Comment: for that you need another ngFor inside ng-container

Comment: yes thats what i am not able to achieve, can you update code so that this for gives me a simple counter

Answer (score 0):

In constructor or when you populate display array filter data with that condition and then loop thrue filtered data:

```
displayKiran = [];

constructor() {
  this.displayKiran = this.display.filter(dis => {
     return dis.name == 'kiran';
  });
}

<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayKiran;let i=index;" >
    <ion-item  text-wrap>
        {{list.i}} {{list.ENTUSR}} {{list.DESCRPITION}}
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```